# How to keep last drawn path and not to get it removed when drawing or touching anywhere in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, touch, gesture

I am making android app and in this I am letting user to draw on specified area. I am using the api demos and it is working well with touch to draw with user fingure movements. but there is a problem , and that is when I draw the path it drawn successfully but redrawing causing the last drawn path to be disappear

I do not know why it is happening I have tried invalidate() and canvas.save() and number of several method which I supposed to used the last path drawn over the canvas but nothing helped me. keep in mind I am drawing the line as the user moves and drags his finger

The code goes like this :

```
 @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);

            canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);


        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if ((mX > 370 && mX < 425) && (mY > 420 && mY < 770)) {
             //if condition ensures that I am drawing in center 
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
         }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "x=" + x + "and Y=" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I do not know why it is removing the last drawing path , and Please some one can assure me How I can track that if user is drawing the line from top to down and it should only draw if the user starts it from starting point to end point I mean from top to bottom of my specified area?

Any clue and link would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
package com.kWh360.image.editing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
    private ArrayList<PathPoints> paths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
    private ArrayList<PathPoints> undonePaths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private int color;
    public int SSL = Color.WHITE;
    private int x, y;
    private int strockWidth = 3;

    private String textToDraw = null;
    public static boolean isTextModeOn = false;

    int mWidth, mHeight;

    public DrawingPanel(Context context, int color, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(context);
        this.color = color;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
        mPaint.setTextSize(30);

        mPath = new Path();
        //paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color,strockWidth, false));
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void changeWidthOfStrock(int strockWidth) {
        this.strockWidth = strockWidth;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        mWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        mHeight = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if(mBitmap != null) {
            float xscale = (float) w / (float) mBitmap.getWidth();
            float yscale = (float) h / (float) mBitmap.getHeight();
            if (xscale > yscale) // make sure both dimensions fit (use the
                xscale = yscale;

            int newx = mWidth;//= (int) ((int) w * xscale);
            int newy = mHeight;//= (int) ((int) h * xscale); // use the same scale for both dimensions
            System.out.println("Screen width-->"+newx);
            System.out.println("Screen height-->"+newy);
            System.out.println("mBitmap.getWidth()-->"+mBitmap.getWidth());
            System.out.println("mBitmap.getHeight()-->"+mBitmap.getHeight());

            if(mBitmap.getWidth() <= newx) {
                newx = mBitmap.getWidth();
            }

            if(mBitmap.getHeight() <= newy) {
                newy = mBitmap.getHeight(); 
            }

            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), true);
            //mBitmap = getResizedBitmap(mBitmap, newx, newy);//Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 453,311, true);
        } else {
            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /*
         * Draw the image into center
         */
        //int cx = (mWidth - mBitmap.getWidth()) >> 1; // same as (...) / 2
        //int cy = (mHeight - mBitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (PathPoints p : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getStrockWidth());
            if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
                //canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
            }
        }
        mPaint.setColor(SSL);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        //mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, SSL,strockWidth ,false));
        mPath = new Path();

    }

    private void drawText(int x, int y) {
        //Log.v(TAG, "Here");
        //Log.v(TAG, "X " + x + " Y " + y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        paths.add(new PathPoints(color, textToDraw, true, x, y));
        // mCanvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (!isTextModeOn) {
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!isTextModeOn) {
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isTextModeOn) {
                drawText((int) x, (int) y);
                invalidate();
            } else {
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }


    class PathPoints {
        private Path path;
        // private Paint mPaint;
        private int color;
        private int strockW;
        private String textToDraw;
        private boolean isTextToDraw;
        private int x, y;

        public PathPoints(Path path, int color,int strockWidth ,boolean isTextToDraw) {
            this.path = path;
            this.color = color;
            this.strockW = strockWidth;
            this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
        }

        public PathPoints(int color, String textToDraw, boolean isTextToDraw,int x, int y) {
            this.color = color;
            this.textToDraw = textToDraw;
            this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Path getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        /*
         * private Paint getPaint() { mPaint = new Paint();
         * mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); mPaint.setColor(color);
         * mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         * mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         * mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
         * return mPaint; }
         */

        public int getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getStrockWidth() {
            return strockW;
        }

        public void setStrokWidth(int color) {
            this.strockW = color;
        }

        public String getTextToDraw() {
            return textToDraw;
        }

        public void setTextToDraw(String textToDraw) {
            this.textToDraw = textToDraw;
        }

        public boolean isTextToDraw() {
            return isTextToDraw;
        }

        public void setTextToDraw(boolean isTextToDraw) {
            this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

    }


     private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

         int cx = (mWidth - mBitmap.getWidth()) >> 1; // same as (...) / 2
         int cy = (mHeight - mBitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

         int width = bm.getWidth();
         int height = bm.getHeight();
         float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
         float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
         // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
         matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

         // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
         //Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, cx, cy, width, height, matrix, false);
         return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, cx, cy, width, height, matrix, false);
     }


}
```

---

Add this drawing view into layout

```
drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(getApplicationContext(), Constant.ImageEdit.colors[0], Constant.PhotoBitmapCommon);
rl_imgEdit_image.addView(drawingPanel);
```

Comment: I do not understand How to add this class and where and How to add this in layout

Comment: Add drawing layout into your layout.

Comment: how please tell me the way of how to use this in my layout also , I do not understand what is Constant.ImageEdit.colors[0], Constant.PhotoBitmapCommon);  
i have replace it with Color.Black , and replaced bitmap with 
 Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth,screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
in your 
drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(getApplicationContext(), Constant.ImageEdit.colors[0], Constant.PhotoBitmapCommon);

Comment: okay now add this drawing penal dynamically to your layout in onCreate().

Comment: its woring great Even I can place dot through it

Comment: Can you please solve my one confusion more or give me the idea ?

Comment: Yes please tell me what is the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88485/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-patel-hiren).

Comment: I want to use to display the icon that would be brush and user would use that brush to draw and of cores user would be using his finger to grab that brush , and should start drawing using that brush , if the brush is not garbed the painting should not occur.